# How to run one method for any amout of varibles

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to run one method for all args passed to function and return them

Here’s an example what i want to achieve:

```
const getAllData = (args) =>{
    args.map((arg)=> useDispatch(arg))
}
return args
```

and call it in another file for example

```
const [var1,var2,var3] = getAllData()
```

or

```
const allVars = getAllData([var1,var2,var3])
```

Comment: `getAllData = (...args) => args.map((arg)=> useDispatch(arg))` however, I'm not sure why that's any better than just doing `[var1, var2, var3].map((arg)=> useDispatch(arg)` without making a separate function.

Answer (score 5):

What you have written is pretty close-- just use the [rest params syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to access the args as an array.  Below is a `processAll` version of this that can accept a processing function and any number of variables to process, and will return them.  See it in action by running the snippet.

```js
const one = 1;
const two = 2;
const three = 3;

function processAll(processor, ...args) {
  const processedArgs = args.map((arg) => processor(arg));
  return processedArgs;
}

function multiplyByTwo(input) {
  return input * 2;
}

const [pTwo, pFour, pSix] = processAll(multiplyByTwo, one, two, three);

console.log(pTwo, pFour, pSix);
```

Comment: "*just use the spread operator two spread out the args.*" what you have is [rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) it's not spreading.

Comment: @VLAZ - good catch, thanks; updated now.

Answer (score 2):

In es6 you can use rest parameter for that!

```js
// Example ----
function add(...nums) {
  // Here nums will be an array
  const sum = nums.reduce((a, c) => a + c);
  console.log(sum);
}

add(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).  You can pass as many variables as you want to the function, and then just loop over `arguments` to get each of them.

```
function getAllData() {
    return Array.from(arguments).map(arg => useDispatch(arg))
}
const allVars = getAllData(var1, var2, var3);
```

---

You can also use ["rest parameters"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to get the arguments as an array.

```
const getAllData = (...args) =>  Array.from(args).map(arg => useDispatch(arg));
const allVars = getAllData(var1, var2, var3);
```

Comment: Arrow functions do not get their own `arguments` the same way they don't get their own `this` - they inherit `arguments` (if any) from the enclosing context.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I just realized that when I was testing the code.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Fixed :-)